# Skrill Payment Gateway Integration in Asp.Net

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, payment-gateway, skrill

I am looking for sample code to integrate skrill payment gateway into my application. I tried with skrill sandbox account and json rpc web method calling, but everytime I got the parse error or cross domain exception.

Please help me out.

I want to register a credit card and later want to make automated payment.

If you have sample code with other language platform than also please share some sample here.

Thanks

Richa Shah

**First Tried with below code:**

```
public static string RegCard()
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://psp.sandbox.dev.skrillws.net/v1/json/3e40a821/channelid_register_get/creditcard/");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"register\",\"id\":1 ,\"params\":{\"account\":{\"number\":\"4111111111111111\",\"expiry\":\"10/2016\",\"cvv\",\"123\"}}}";
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }
            var responseText="";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //Now you have your response.
                //or false depending on information in the response
                return responseText;
            }
        }
```

**Second Try with**

```
   function Register2() {
                    $.post("https://psp.sandbox.dev.skrillws.net/v1/json/3e40a821/channelid_register_get/creditcard", "{'jsonrpc\" : \"2.0\",\"method\" : \"register\",\"params\" : {\"account\":{\"number\":\"4444333322221111\",\"expiry\":\"10/2016\",\"cvv\",\"333\"} },\"id\":1 }", function (data, textStatus) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    }, "json");
                }
                function RegisterCard() {

                    var jsonText = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0","method" : "register","params" : {"account":{"number":"4444333322221111","expiry":"10/2016","cvv","333"} },"id":1}';
                    // "{'number':" + JSON.stringify(jsonText) + "}"
                    try {
                        $(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "https://psp.sandbox.dev.skrillws.net/v1/json/3e40a821/channelid_register_get/creditcard?jsoncallback=?",
                                data: jsonText,
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                callback: 'RegisterCardResponse',
                                dataType: "json"
                            });
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert(e);
                    }
                }
                function RegisterCardResponse(response) {
                    alert(1);
                    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = response;
                }
```

**Third Try with**

```
function RegisterCard() {

                    var jsonText = '{"jsonrpc" : "2.0","method" : "register","params" : {"account":{"number":"4444333322221111","expiry":"10/2016","cvv","333"} },"id":1}';
                    try {
                        $(function () {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "https://psp.sandbox.dev.skrillws.net/v1/json/3e40a821/channelid_register_get/creditcard",
                                data: jsonText,
                                contentType: "application/json",                               
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                    var value = responseData.someKey;
                                    RegisterCardResponse(responseData);
                                },
                                error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                                    alert(responseData);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert(e);
                    }
                }
                function RegisterCardResponse(response) {
                    alert(1);
                    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = response;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution to Access Skrill Json RPC Method**

**In ASPX Page Write Below code In Javascript:**

```
`<input type="button" onclick="RegCard(); return false;" value="Register" />

<script type="text/javascript">
 function RegCard() {


                    var request = {};
                    request.method = "register";
                    request.params = {};
                    request.params.account = {};
                    request.params.account.number = "Card Number";
                    request.params.account.expiry = "Expiry Date";
                    request.params.account.cvv = "CVV Number";
                    request.id = 1;
                    request.jsonrpc = "2.0";

                    $(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "SkrillHandler.ashx",
                            data: { 'a': 'register', 'data': JSON.stringify(request) },
                            contentType: "application/json",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (responseData) {
                                alert(responseData.result.account.token);
                            },
                            error: function (responseData) {
                                alert(responseData);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                    //$.getJSON('SkrillHandler.ashx', { data: JSON.stringify(request) }, function (a) {
                    //    //displayTweets(a);
                    //});

                    //$.post(url, JSON.stringify(request), displaySearchResult, "json");
                }
</script>`
```

**Now Create Generic Handler Named SkrillHandler.ashx**

```
'public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {            
            string responseText = "";
            if (context.Request.QueryString["a"].ToString() == "register")
            {
                responseText = RegisterCard(context.Request.QueryString["data"].ToString());
            }
            context.Response.Write(responseText);
        }

        private string RegisterCard(string data)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://psp.sandbox.dev.skrillws.net/v1/json/3e40a821/channelid_register_get/creditcard/");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = data;
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }
            var responseText = "";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                //Now you have your response.
                //or false depending on information in the response
            }
            return responseText;
        }
'
```

You will get the response from Javascript RegCard Method.